# REACT/REDUX, show user when signed in and not show when signed out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using react/redux and attempting to use the react life-cycle methods to get this to work. I will do a step by step of what I want to happen and what is happening.

I will post all code below that I think is needed to figure this out. If you need something additional please comment below and I will add it in an edit instead of replying that way the comments don't get to compiled.

What I want:

1. User inputs sign in data and clicks sign in
2. User is signed in and their email shows in the header component
3. User clicks sign out and is taken to the sign out component
4. As the user is taken to the sign out component their email does not show anymore

What is happening:

1. User inputs sign in data and clicks sign in
2. User is signed in and the email does not show in the header component until hard refresh is done
3. User clicks sign out and is taken to the sign out component
4. As the user is taken to the sign out component their email shows up still until hard refresh is done

Header component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../actions/index';

class Header extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.authenticated) {
      this.props.getUser();
    }
  }

  renderLinks() {
    if(this.props.authenticated) {
      return [
        <li className="nav-item" key={1}>
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/signout">Sign Out</Link>
        </li>,
        <li className="nav-item" key={2}>
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/posts/new">Create New Post</Link>
        </li>,
        <li className="nav-item" key={3}>
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/posts">Posts</Link>
        </li>
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        <li className="nav-item" key={4}>
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/signin">Sign In</Link>
        </li>,
        <li className="nav-item" key={5}>
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/signup">Sign Up</Link>
        </li>
      ];
    }
  }

  renderUser() {
    if(this.props.user) {
      return (
        <li className="nav-item" key={this.props.user.id}>
          {this.props.user.email}
        </li>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.user);
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Ghost Hunters</Link>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
          {this.renderLinks()}
        </ul>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {this.renderUser()}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
    user: state.user
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Header);
```

Sign out Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

class Signout extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.signoutUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Sorry to see you go...</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(Signout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent will call getUser only when the component mounts and that's only done once. It looks like you need to call getUser after a successful login or just put the user properties in the state, update the state after login and let react and redux handle the UI updates for you.

Comment: That worked for the login part now I need to get it to work when the user logs out. I am using a JWT token which is stored in the localstorage. When the user signs out the token is removed. But for some reason the email does not disappear when the user signs out.

Comment: I just had to make an action to clear the user state!